# Stop a sticky service programmatically

Tags: android, service, sticky

I need a sticky service so that in case it is destroyed by the system it gets recreated, but I need it to stop working once the user logs out of the app.

Service.stopSelf() or Context.stopService(Intent) do not seem to work....
what should I do then? There must be a way...

Answer (score 1):

Call stopService(intent_of_your_service) at onPause() or onDestroy().
Here, intent_of_your_service is the Intent you created at onCreate() or elsewhere.

Moreover, I am sure that stopSelf() works fine (i.e., it stops the service) even if it is a sticky service. From where did you call it?

Comment: onPause and onDestroy of what component?